# Jest: Expect a function inside component to have been called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, formik

Hi have this simple piece of code inspired by https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-formik/

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Field, Form } from "formik";

const sleep = (ms: any) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));

export const MyForm = () => {
  const handleSubmit = async (values: any) => {
    await sleep(500);
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          firstName: "",
        }}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <Form>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Jane" />

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and the Test:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

import { MyForm } from "./MyForm";

test("rendering and submitting a basic Formik form", async () => {
  const handleSubmit = jest.fn(); // this doing nothing
  render(<MyForm />);
  const user = userEvent.setup();

  await user.type(screen.getByLabelText(/first name/i), "John");

  await user.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /submit/i }));

  await waitFor(() => expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
});
```

Console.log printed the inputed value: `{ firstName: 'John' }`, but the test fails due the fact it understand that `handleSubmit` was not been called.

What’s going wrong with this code?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Expected call (1) got (0).

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't pass the mock `handleSubmit` to `<MyForm/>` component. You should pass it to the component as `onSubmit` prop and call it when the internal `handleSubmit` event handler executes.

Let's see the [RTL official formik testing example](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-formik/)

`MyForm.tsx`:

```
export const MyForm = ({onSubmit}) => {
  const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    await sleep(500)
    onSubmit(values)
  }
  return <div>...</div>
}
```

`MyForm.test.tsx`:

```
test('rendering and submitting a basic Formik form', async () => {
  const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
  render(<MyForm onSubmit={handleSubmit} />);

  await user.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: /submit/i}));

  await waitFor(() => expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
})
```

Did you see the difference between the official example and your code?

Comment: Yes, I notice this and know this way is working properly. My doubt is about, my specific example, when I don’t want to pass the `handleSubmit ` to outside the `<MyForm>` component.  Why, there is no way to mock the `handleSubmit` this way?

Comment: @Joel react function component is js function，no special. handleSubmit is defined in this function scope ，it’s private. If you can’t access it, then you can’t mock it. The best practice is to test the behavior of the component, not implementation details, you don’t need to assert some method has been called or not What happened when form submit?console.log() don’t have too much meaning. Test the component as a user, using black-box testing

Comment: @slideshop2. Make all sense, that's what I suspected, thanks for clarifying. If needed, you can edit your post with the answer provided, I will mark it as a solution.